# Find dimension of subspace with condition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How can I find the dimension of this subspace rapidly? So far, I've tried putting the columns in reduced row echelon form and simply taking out the last one but that won't work.
$$V=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{c} v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ v_4\end{array}\right]\in\text{Span}\left\{\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{r} 0\\ -1\\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 2\\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 2\\ 1\end{array}\right]\right\}\ \text{such as}\ v_4=0\right\}.$$

Comment: Note that $2\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)^t$, and $e_1= (1,1,0,1)^t$, $e_2=(0,-1,1,0)^t$, $e_3=(0,2,0,1)^t$, $e_4=(0,0,2,1)^t$.

$v$ is in the span, so for some $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$, $v=a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_3+a_4e_4$. Looking at the fourth coordinate implies $a_4=-a_1-a_3$. So, if we let $f_1=e_1-e_3$, $f_3=e_3-e_4$ we have $v=a_1f_1+a_2e_2+a_3f_3$. Moreover, any such vector is in your set $V$.

So, $V$ is the span of $f_1$, $e_2$, $f_3$. See how many of them are linearly independent to obtain your dimension.